# Randomly change the position of radio button in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am working on a Quiz App and I want to shuffle the options of the question. So everyone should see different positions of options. I'm using a radio button. So I can approach this goal. Will you please help me.

Comment: add your code sample

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you can show us your code. But assuming that you pass the radio buttons to a column from a list of widget

```
List<Widget> options =[option1, option2,option3]
.
.
.
Column(children: options)
```

then you can shuffle the options list once the values are loaded

```
options.shuffle();
```

hope it works